# Processing batch of files with multi-threaded environment

Tags: python, multithreading

I am fairly new to python so this might come out as a basic question, but please bear with me. I am try to process a bunch of audio files present in a directory. But since the number of files is very huge the process takes up to hours. Since the task I am doing/applying it redundant, I am planning on multi-threading the whole thing, with each thread processing a batch of files.

Now I don't know what the files names are in advance and I have no idea how many files are in the directory, I can only know these thing when I run the program and actually analyze the path. Here is my confusion with multi-threading this problem:

> How does a thread know which file falls under it's batch?

If I had some file listing all these files I could easily split this list into chunks using pandas or similar library to assign workload to each thread, but in current scenario when I don't have list of files before hand I confused which library to use(if any). Any suggestion?

A work around would be to create a list of all file names at start of program but I think that would be in-efficient as I have files that can range from any where between 10'000 to 20'000.

Answer (score 0):

As you need each file to be worked on exactly once, you need to coordinate your threads to ensure no conflicts. This does mean specifying the work for each thread - that is, giving each thread an explicit set of files. You could do this by getting the entire list of files and splitting it, or you could give each thread a "start at" and "stop at" path and have them go through the files alphabetically.

If you're in a Linux environment, another approach would be to have your python script accept a single path to work on at a time then use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) or similar to run multiple processes:

```
ls target_directory | xargs -l -P4 python processing_script.py
```

This command will run your processing script on all the files in the target directory, using 4 processes. The number of processes is specified by the number after `-P`.

As Sraw mentioned in the comments, splitting the task across many processes or threads may not actually speed it up; you should benchmark and compare approaches.